# pushing clicked button ID's into array using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have 5 buttons with several ids. The ids are random names. I am trying to push this ID name into the array called myClicks. What is the most easiest solution for this. I tried pushing in "data.id" and "id" but none work; The array remains empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function MyCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.foo = "I'm foo!";
            $scope.lines = [];
            $scope.myClicks=[];
             id=$scope.id;
            $scope.clickme = function(){
                //alert("test");
                $scope.lines.push($scope.lines.length);
                $scope.myClicks.push({id});
                console.log('user'+ 'path was as followed');

                
            }
       
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <button id="uno" ng-click="clickme()"ng-model="data.id">Path A</button><br>
        <button id="dos" ng-click="clickme()" ng-model="data.id">Path B</button><br>
        <button is="cuatro" ng-click="clickme()" ng-model="data.id">Path C</button><br>
        <button id="cinco" ng-click="clickme()" ng-model="data.id">Path D</button><br>
        <button id="sieta" ng-click="clickme()" ng-model="data.id" value="dadsa">Path E</button>

        <div ng-repeat="line in lines">
           UserPath:{{myClicks}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try pushing $scope.id rather than id and check it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.lines_dic    = {}
            $scope.clickme = function(val){
                if(val in $scope.lines_dic){
                        alert('Already Present')
                        return
                }
                $scope.lines_dic[val]      = 1;
            }
            $scope.values       = function(){
                        return Object.keys($scope.lines_dic);
           }
       
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <button id="uno" ng-click="clickme('uno')" ng-model="data.id">Path A</button><br>
        <button id="dos" ng-click="clickme('dos')" ng-model="data.id">Path B</button><br>
        <button is="cuatro" ng-click="clickme('cuatro')" ng-model="data.id">Path C</button><br>
        <button id="cinco" ng-click="clickme('cinco')" ng-model="data.id">Path D</button><br>
        <button id="sieta" ng-click="clickme('sieta')" ng-model="data.id" value="dadsa">Path E</button>

        <div>
           UserPath:{{values()}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```